# Footer sticking to the bottom issue

Tags: html, css

I've tried ways to make this work. Mainly been trying [this solution](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page).

That didn't work out for me. The issue I do see is that in my body html css, I do have the height set up 100%, but its not really setting it to 100%.

Here is my css code for my footer and body, html:

```
body {
font-family: 'AG-Regular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
min-width: 1058px;
}

body, html {
height:100% !important;
}

#footerBox {
    width: 100%;
height:218px;
background-image:url(/img/footer-bg.png);
background-attachment:scroll;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

[Here is a link to the site](http://www2.pmxusercon.com).

You should see where it's messed up at. Any help would be appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to attach the form to the white strip at the bottom?

Comment: I'm trying to hide that white strip at the bottom entirely. I just want the footer to stick to the bottom with the red background extended to it.

Comment: I just updated a little bit of the CSS. I had the #pushBox classified with #footerBox when it was suppose to be with #mainBox. That sorta fixed it, I still have the white strip at the bottom.

Comment: Set like this #footerContent {padding: 20px 30px;}

Comment: It's the padding. EDIT: got ninja'd.

Comment: I just did that, helps a bit. I think the main problem is, my body html is not really setting its height at 100% on the page. Only setting it 100% within my containers.

Comment: Check again tutorial you've followed, I think you've missed some things.

Comment: I went back to the tutorial and I added some pieces missing to the puzzle. It seems to be one thing after another. It's working nicely now, the only thing is, when the page extends to its maximum, it still forces you to scroll down to fully view the footer. Any way around that? I've been messing around with it in firebug, no solution could be found yet.

Answer (score 1):

To get the header and footer to stick you need to use position: fixed on both.

**Example Code**

**Header**

```
#headerBox
{
    position: fixed;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Main**

```
#mainBox
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Footer**

```
#footerBox
{
     postion: fixed;
     height: 218px;
     width: 100%;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Main problem was the `-218px margin-bottom` in `#maincontent`. Make this `218px` so that your footer is pushed down. I set your footer to always be on the bottom of the page using `position: fixed`, not sure if this is what you wanted or not.

```
#footerBox {
width: 100%;
height: 218px;
background-image: url(/img/footer-bg.png);
background-attachment: scroll;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
}
#mainBox #mainContent {
background-color: white;
margin: 185px auto 218px;
overflow: auto;
padding: 30px 20px 20px;
width: 958px;
}
```

Comment: Very close to what I'm looking for, except I don't want the footer to go over the content like that. Not like the navigation menu.